# Click event hide 2 components Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, binding

I've 1 root component with 3 sub-componenet where I put some @input to get the click event who's call them successfully to the view, so when I click on the root I want to open a sub-component (that's work fine) but in the same time I would like the two others disappear from the view and so on for each one but separately (kind of div.hidden)...if you need more code or explanations don't hesitate....thanks in advance

Here's my root component.html:

```
    <div class="daydetail">
    <h1>Detail of day</h1>
 <button pButton class="daydetail" type="button" icon="fa-chevron-up" label="Click"(click)="toggleChild()"></button>
     <div>
         <my-daydetail [showMePartially]="showVar"></my-daydetail>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dailyreport">
    <h1>Daily</h1>
    <my-dailyreport></my-dailyreport>
</div> 

<div class="inventory">
    <my-inventory></my-inventory>
</div>
```

Here's my root component.ts:

```
export class AppliV2Component   {
   showVar = false;
   hideVar = true;

  constructor(public userService: UserService) {
    }
   toggleChild() {
       this.showVar = !this.showVar;
       this.hideVar = !this.hideVar;
       }
}
```

First child.html:

```
<div *ngIf="hideMePartially" class="dailyreport">
     <h1>Daily report</h1>
</div> <!-- Fin de dailyreport -->
```

First child.ts:

```
export class MyDailyreportComponent implements OnInit {


 @Input() hideMePartially: boolean;
  constructor() { }
```

Second child.html:

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="daydetail2" > <!-- this part will be toggled by the parent component button  -->


<h1>Informations</h1>
</div>
```

Second child.ts:

```
  export class MyInventoryComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() hideMePartially: boolean;
```

Comment: In the root component.html  code, ``hideMePartially`` is not passed to ``<my-dailyreport></my-dailyreport>`` as ``input``.

Comment: @SameerK thanks that's right I forget to put it in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *ngIf will not hide / show the component. It will add / remove it. There's a difference. To hide component you should use `[hidden]="true/false"`

In your case you could do something like:

```
<div [hidden]="displayDetail" class="daydetail2" >
```

And then just create **displayDetail** variable of type boolean in your component typescript.

After that, you can easily create toggle method to set the **displayDetail** to true or false.

```
toggleDisplay(){
  this.displayDetail != this.displayDetail;
}
```

You can invoke that method in template.

```
<button (click)="toggleDisplay();"> Toggle Button </button>
```

**NOTE:** the CSS for [hidden] could be overwritten so you might want to add this to your component CSS

```
[hidden] { display: none !important;}
```

Comment: many thanks for your help I'll try this out then let you know

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes

Comment: the thing is I would like the [hidden] benn call also by the same button as  <button pButton class="daydetail" type="button" icon="fa-chevron-up" label="Click"(click)="toggleChild()"></button> comming from the root component

Comment: From what I've understand so far, you should check how communication between components works. You just have to manage to send the displayDetail variable from root component to child component. Rest should be simple, just follow the logic from my answer.

Comment: or maybe should I add another input in my child component nor an output to know when the first child is clicked then hidden the second?

Comment: I try this out and I think I implement your solution correctly (with the css) but when I open the root component by the click I still see some of the hidden div behind my div comming from the root (it delete some few pieces of the text)

Comment: I did some more testing and in fact the hidden works ! it delete the text and so on from the child but when the div comming from the root component is display on it's like the border from the child div are still visible..I would like to post a picture but I don' know how to do that in a comment

Comment: Maybe the z-index css?

Comment: Many many thanks for all I found the way to make it disapear it was about the css absolute position

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I helped